# Why is 'Remove Assignments' in User Assigned Roles section always disabled in Azure AD developer portal?

Tags: azure

I have assigned all roles to a user, but this user is still unable to remove any role assignments for itself or other users in User Assigned Roles section. The 'Remove Assignments' tab is greyed out. What should I do to enable this 'Remove assignments' tab? You can click the link below to see the screenshot.

[image: screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGMX3.jpg)

Comment: Make that user as a User Administrator or Global Admin and that should resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, the user has both user admiistrator and global admin privileges. this user is able to add role assignments, but not remove role assignments. You can see them from my original screenshot that add assignment tab is enabled but remove assignment tab is shomehow disabled. I even added all privileges to this user and again remove assignment tab is disabled.